# Do Surgical Teams exist?

Tags: methodology

Has anybody been in or has seen a kind of "Surgical Team" as described in The Mythical Man Month? Have you heard of somebody actually implementing "Mill's Proposal"?

There is a lot of detail about the various roles in the book itself, but for those who haven't read the book, I found a [website](http://www.dfpug.de/loseblattsammlung/online/workshop/design_patterns/sonstiges.htm) and a [blog post](http://runtimelog.blogspot.com/2005/06/mythical-surgical-team_10.html) which give a good summary. I've quoted the roles from the website below:

> **The Surgical Team**
>
> - The **surgeon** is the chief programmer and the el-presidente of the whole
>     team. He produces all the
>     specifications, codes the entire
>     system the team is responsible for,
>     tests it, and drafts its supporting
>     documentation.
> - The **copilot** is the surgeon’s assistant. His main purpose is to
>     share in the thinking about design
>     issues – to serve as a sounding board,
>     as it were. The copilot represents the
>     team in meetings with other teams. He
>     knows the code intimately, and serves
>     as insurance in case of disaster to
>     the surgeon.
> - The **toolsmith** supports the surgeon and builds specialized utilities and
>     tools as may be required by his
>     surgeon. Each team has its dedicated
>     toolsmith in addition to any central
>     services provided by the rest of the
>     project infrastructure. The tester is
>     responsible for maintaining test cases
>     for testing the surgeon’s work as he
>     writes it. He is both an adversary who
>     devises test cases to measure against
>     the formal specs and devises test data
>     to be used in debugging.
> - The **language lawyer**, which can serve several surgeons, I a widely consulted
>     specialist who delights in the mastery
>     of the intricacies of the programming
>     languages and the operating systems
>     upon which the software must perform.
> - The **administrator** handles money, people, space, and machines. The
>     surgeon is the ultimate boss, with the
>     last word on all these issues, but the
>     day to day management of the issues
>     and interfacing with the
>     administrative machinery of the
>     project is the role of a professional
>     administrator. One administrator may
>     serve more than one team.
> - The **editor** edits and revises the documentation as drafted or dictated
>     by the surgeon and oversees the
>     mechanics of its production.
> - The **program clerk**, trained as a secretary, is responsible for
>     maintaining all the  machine-readable
>     and human-readable technical records
>     generated by the team. All the filing
>     and indexing is the responsibility of
>     the program clerk.
> - The **secretaries** handle the project correspondence and non-project files.
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz0H7.gif]

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer if you describe both terms and/or link to their descriptions.

Comment: I've added some descriptions for the roles, it's not as detailed as in the book, but it should give you a good idea. Personally I would love to have a toolsmith :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did use the surgical team approach of Brooks' at a startup we set up about 10 years ago. We were five people at the company plus a few others at the uni lab supporting us. The experience was technically great, but it didn't last long for business reasons. :-)

Comment: sounds interesting. Care to expand at all? I'm quite interested in your experience and how it compares to other projects you've worked on :)

Comment: I was looking to cleanup my old questions and thought about deleting this one, since I neglected it, but it seems someone actually improved it and answered it. Well done! :) I'll deduce that probably no such teams exist in practice and there are no success stories.

Comment: @JacobStanley, Interesting. I can't believe language lawyers actually exist. What does the language lawyer actually do then in a typical work day?